# LwIP pbuf components and memory management for stm32f207 mcu based udp server implementation

Tags: memory-management, udp, embedded, stm32, lwip

I'm trying to understand the documents (having in mind this stm32 document: AN3384 [link for download](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stsw-stm32060.html#documentation)), stm32 examples and comments on some source files from this stack (LwIP) in order to choose the correct options for my application.

According to the literature I see there are 3 types of pbuf: **ROM**, **RAM** and **POOL**.

Some authors say that:

1. **PBUF_POOL** can be managed as a pools of dynamic memory (heap) that can be freed after being used. But it can also be used as static memory pools. But reading literature "pbuf allocation is performed from a pool of statically pre-allocated pbufs".
2. The way for having static or dynamic pbufs is enabling one of this two options: **MEM_USE_POOLS** or **MEMP_MEM_MALLOC**.
3. Source code comment says about **PBUF_POOL**: "pbuf payload refers to RAM. This one comes from a pool and should be used for RX... Don't use this for TX with TCP packets".
4. **PBUF_ROM** is for constant data payload that doesn't change.
5. **PBUF_RAM** only can be used as a dynamic ram memory. So: you must to define only **MEMP_MEM_MALLOC**.

As this questions are not clear for me on literature documents, web pages and source comments I have read I need it to clarify them:

- Regarding point 1: Are they only static objects or can they be treated as both static and dynamic elements?
- Regarding point 2: is it true that defining **MEMP_MEM_MALLOC** I would have all the pbufs dynamically allocated? and defining **MEM_USE_POOLS** is used for having all the pbuf statically allocated.
- Regarding point 3: If I'm not wrong I can only define one way for memory managing on (found on opt.h options LwIP stack file): static or dynamic (**MEM_USE_POOLS** or not). If I enable static memory for reception incoming pbuf, how could I work with non static pbuf for transmission packets if I've defined static memory (in order to have received pbuf statically allocated)? Can static buffers (**PBUF_POOL**) be used packets transmission if packets are UDP ones?
- Regarding point 4: I guess in case of need of pbuf_rom the opt.h option to be defined (enabled) must be static memory: **MEM_USE_POOLS**.
- Regarding pint 5: is this assertion true?

I'm a bit confused and I'm not sure if the options I'have explained are correctly understood by me. So, please let me know which of them are missunderstunding.